# import java.awt.Desktop is not resolved in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, email, uri

I have to use `Desktop.getDesktop().mail(URI)` for a requirement in my project. The import `java.awt.Desktop` is not getting resolved in my Eclipse IDE. I understand that this works on Java6. However, is there any way I could accomplish this in Eclipse?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You mean u are coding in eclipse without java? I believe you need to add appropriate library for it.

Comment: What is the name of *class* that you've created? Is it `Desktop`?

Comment: And what would that library be? I had written ~ 50 java classes for my project extensively using swing and awt classes in Eclipse without any issues. But this one caught me! As Eclipse has its own compiler, I believe there should be a way out (of course by loading an external jar or something).

Comment: What minimum Java version are you aiming to support?

Comment: @AVD: Its not Desktop. Its "aboutPanel". I don't think its an issue with the class name. This is what I am trying:
`try{
           Desktop.getDesktop().mail(new URI("mailto:" + address + "?subject=TodoList: Hi"));
            
        }
        catch(URISyntaxException | IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception in opening outlook");
        }`

But `import java.awt.Desktop` is not getting resolved in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

java.awt.Desktop support only on Java 1.6 onwards. If you are  using java 1.5 in eclipse as the default compiler option for your project, then better change it to Java 1.6

Comment: The `Desktop` class was available through [javadesktop.org](http://www.javadesktop.org/articles/jdic/index.html), but the links to the API itself are now dead.  Compelled to add though, that changing the minimum version of an app. for just one (replaceable) method seems overkill to me.

Comment: You are right Andrew. System.getProperty("java.runtime.version") tells me my Eclipse is running with **1.5.0_06-b05**. Either I _have to_ upgrade to 1.6.x or live without this api :(

Comment: *"Either I have to upgrade to 1.6.x or live without this api :("*  That is incorrect.  Or rather there are other ways to do it (e.g. `BrowerLauncher2`).  But then, I'm still waiting on an answer to my question of which version the app. is intended to support.  1.5 is getting quite old.

Comment: Alright, this problem actually turned out to be a blessing in disguise. I upgraded to jdk 1.7 and changed the eclipse Compiler compliance to use this. Also, now I am running on JRE 7. Pheww, I am all good now! Of course, now it would be supported on 1.6 onwards...   Thanks Andrew and UVM.

Comment: This is not correct - the compiler level just affects the syntax and bytecode generation, not the content of the runtime library.  You need to add a new JVM to what Eclipse knows and then tell Eclipse to use that JVM for your project.